# How does a "mains priority circuit work"?

Tags: power-supply, switching, appliances

Dometic makes a series of DC refrigerators and one capability is to hook the fridge up to both DC and AC and it uses a "mains priority circuit" to prefer the AC source to the DC source, if both are present. This can be either built into the fridge or come as a separate accessory that they call a [mains adapter](https://www.dometic.com/en/se/products/food-and-beverage/coolers/accessories/dometic-coolpower-mps-35-_-64052). Unfortunately, they do not supply detailed schematics for either their fridges or their adapter, so I cannot tell how this circuit works.

How does this type of circuit work?

Comment: What does *Dometic* mean?

Comment: @Andyaka it's a brand specialising in low power appliances, e.g. for boats, caravans..

Answer (score 2):

I don't know but given the challenge I would do something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFLzyC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A relay solution. When mains is present it supplies the fridge power and disconnects the battery.*

It is more likely that they have used a solid-state solution rather than a relay but the principle will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is an internal relay, the AC supply powers it, and keeps the DC disconnected, when AC is lost, the relay falls back to normally closed and is connected to DC,

When AC returns, the relay is switched and the DC disconnected, with likely a bridge rectifier for the circuit meaning they do not need to worry about back feeding DC to the grid, equally the DC input likely has a diode to prevent back feeding to the DC source.

If they are lazier it may just be a Diode "OR" circuit, where whichever has the higher voltage is what is powering it right now.